# Media carousel memory leak in React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, video, memory-leaks, native

I'm building an app in React Native using Expo that should run on FireTV devices to show ads and news on TV's. For that I built a component to handle the display of those medias in a loop and that should run perpetually with minimal interaction with the device.

The problem is that memory is leaking. I have managed to slow down the pace of the leak but I can't stop it. It happens with images and videos (with videos the pace of the leakage is higher). But I noticed that a bug in the code was not triggering the re-render of the component when I had only one video in the array and that seemed to stop the leakage (I still need to run more tests on this).

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I'm trying to upload the image of the chart of the memory usage over time with data gathered from ADB using a tool that i built for this project but it's not working, I'm going to try to post it after.

The code of the component:

```
import { ResizeMode, Video } from 'expo-av';
import { Image } from 'expo-image';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import { Media } from '../../@types';
import { logError } from '../../utils/telemetry';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default function Carousel({ medias }: { medias: Media[] }) {
  const [currentMediaIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const videoRef = useRef<Video>(null);

  const currentMedia = medias[currentMediaIndex];

  const aspectRatio =
    currentMedia.height && currentMedia.width
      ? currentMedia.height / currentMedia.width
      : 0;
  const vertical = aspectRatio > 1;

  const mediaStyle = {
    width: windowWidth,
    height: vertical ? windowHeight * aspectRatio : windowHeight,
    transform: vertical ? [{ rotate: '-90deg' }] : 'none',
  };

  const mediaTimer = () => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        try {
          await unloadVideoMemory();
        } catch (error: any) {
          console.log(error);
          setNextIndex();
        }
      }
    }, currentMedia.time);
  };

  const setNextIndex = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => {
      const nextIndex = prevIndex + 1;
      return nextIndex <= medias.length - 1 ? nextIndex : 0;
    });
  };

  const onMediaError = (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
    setNextIndex();
  };

  const unloadVideoMemory = async () => {
    if (videoRef?.current) {
      try {
        await videoRef.current.unloadAsync();
        setNextIndex();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setNextIndex();
      }
    } else {
      setNextIndex();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {currentMedia.type === 'video' ? (
        <Video
          source={{
            uri: currentMedia.Filepath,
          }}
          useNativeControls={false}
          resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
          style={mediaStyle}
          shouldPlay
          positionMillis={0}
          isMuted
          ref={videoRef}
          onError={onMediaError}
          onLoad={mediaTimer}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: currentMedia.Filepath,
          }}
          transition={500}
          style={mediaStyle}
          onError={onMediaError}
          contentFit="contain"
          cachePolicy="none"
          onLoad={mediaTimer}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried setting the key prop on the Video and Image components based on the index of the media and with the counter of the played medias but it didn't work. I tried to separate the back from the front and the problem is on the front-end. I'm also trying to clean the memory of the app programmatically but the priority is to solve the memory leakage.

Comment: The chart of mem/time:

https://postimg.cc/8srC8wR0